# Trouble rendering Kdenlive project

Tags: kdenlive

I'm using Kdenlive to edit a slide / music presentation on Ubuntu 17.04.  I can render small segments but when I try the full project (10 minutes), it crashes with an error message. "This computer doesn't have enough room in the melt file to generate a report." (not the exact text) The render log is below. I'm also having trouble with multiple crashes during editing. There seems to be plenty of room on the computer.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
n

Rendering of `/home/norm/elements.mp4` crashed

```
[libx264 @ 0x94a0bb00] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9310bcc0] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x93126de0] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x93113dc0] stream 0, timescale not set
[swscaler @ 0x891dc820] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[mp4 @ 0x94a0b020] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead. [mp4 @ 0x94a0b020] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x682e9ea0] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x70a03da0] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x83c6d140] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x83cf7000]
stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x70a24aa0]
stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x323eb440]
stream 0, timescale not set
(melt:4298): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed (melt:4298): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed (melt:4298): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```